# Test whether a type T is among the types of a tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, variadic

On SO, I asked for a way to do it [without variadics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23711057/2567683). I also provided a typical "normal" implementation **with variadics**:

```
template <typename V, typename T>
struct Is_in_tuple;

template <typename V, typename T0, typename... T>
struct Is_in_tuple <V, tuple<T0, T...> >
{
  static const bool value = Is_in_tuple<V, tuple<T...> >::value;
};

template <typename V, typename... T>
struct Is_in_tuple <V, tuple<V, T...> >
{
  static const bool value = true;
};

template <typename V>
struct Is_in_tuple <V, tuple<> >
{
  static const bool value = false;
};
```

I'd like a review on the above code. Is it safe / OK / missing something, before I make it my **standard way of querying type lists?**

Answer (score 7):

Since you're implementing a traits-like check, I would typically expect your traits class types to be derived from `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`. This is certainly not required, and overall this implementation doesn't bug me. I was slightly surprised to see `std::tuple<>` called out explicitly, but that doesn't seem to change the overall correctness in any way.

The biggest question I have is how exact you want your type matching to be. Do you require exact type matches like `std::is_same<T, U>` or usably similar types like `std::is_convertible<T, U>`? To be concrete, what should `Is_in_tuple<decltype(0), std::tuple<unsigned int>>::value` be? It would be great to have some unit tests that document this sort of edge case.

The only thing I see wrong with your implementation is by implication: either you must have included some form of `using`, either `using namespace std;` or `using std::tuple;`, or you are dependent on someone else having done so before including this header. While correct use of `using` is fine, particularly in implementation files or inside functions, I would strongly suggest avoiding it here where it will pollute (or require previous pollution of) the compilation unit of whatever code includes this.

Comment: This review sent me down a long path trying to figure out how to implement the above traits check without depending on `std::tuple`. I finally succeeded, and in doing so, I'm tempted to say that the dependency on `std::tuple` is another potential mistake. But evaluating whether it's a mistake depends on knowing whether your code uses just `std::tuple` or other custom variadic template classes.